# App Center build times out for production builds for native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio-app-center

We are trying to use App Center for CI/CD for our native iOS app. It works well for the beta/development builds. The build time is around 30 mins or less. But for production builds we are always facing timeout errors with build time more than one hour.

We have checked Xcode build settings and there isn't any significant difference between the prod and development schemes. Also, App Center's build configuration is similar for both branches except for the certificates and release destination. But the build time is a lot more(30 mins) for production builds. How can we reduce the build time for Production builds in AppCenter?

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this for a few weeks. A few articles recommend disabling flipper at build time, that may help you:

https://medium.com/salt-pepper/reduce-appcenter-ios-build-by-the-time-50-667ac0eef0e4

That didn't help me because we don't use flipper. There doesn't really appear to be any other solution for app center.

We just migrated to azure pipelines, the migration was pretty smooth following the official guide. Still using appcenter for distribution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/export-to-azure-pipelines